# Dateformatter gives wrong time on conversation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert my date string to `NSDate` but its return correct date and wrong time.

This is my code :

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-20 12:10:40";

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *lastUpdatedate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSLog(@"lastUpdatedate : %@",lastUpdatedate);
```

It returns this :

```
lastUpdatedate : 2013-12-20 06:40:40 +0000
```

Comment: the time is 24 or 12 hour format ??

Comment: then will suggest you to convert your date into string and check log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- [NSDate description]` (which is called when passing it to `NSLog`) always prints the date object in GMT timezone, not your local timezone. If you want an accurate string representation of the date, use a date formatter to create a correct string according to your timezone.

Answer (score 2):

As @Leo Natan said,  `- [NSDate description]` always gives date in GMT timezone. If you want to convert into local timezone then use following code.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-20 12:10:40";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *lastUpdatedate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"lastUpdatedate : %@",[self getLocalTime:lastUpdatedate]);



-(NSDate *) getLocalTime:(NSDate *)date {
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: date];
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: date];
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

lastUpdatedate : 2013-12-20 12:10:40 +0000

Comment: How to get only 12:10:40 (Not the whole  date  like 2013-12-20 12:10:40 +0000) and in 24 hours format?

Comment: @natasha HH:mm:ss will gives data format in 24hrs and hh:mm:ss will gives data format in 12 hrs

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-20 12:10:40";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTest = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterTest setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatterTest setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate *d = [dateFormatterTest dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Set NSLocale in your code, and you get perfect result.

Comment: the default locale is the current locale, and it's useless.

Comment: The problem is not that he didn't set a locale. The problem is he didn't use a date formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

NSDate *lastUpdatedate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

NSTimeInterval sourceGMTOffset = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:lastUpdatedate];

lastUpdatedate = [lastUpdatedate dateByAddingTimeInterval:sourceGMTOffset];

NSLog(@"lastUpdatedate : %@",lastUpdatedate);
```

Comment: This modifies the parsed `NSDate` object, and is incorrect.

Comment: @LeoNatan I didn't get you. Please eloberate more.